# JQuery syntax issue with screen width

Tags: jquery

Please look over my syntax here. I am getting the following error: 
Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to append a new stylesheet if the screen resolution is less then or equal to 1024 pixels wide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((screen.width<=1024)) {
     $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />');
  }
});
```

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me on Chrome. You have an extra set of parens around your if clause.

Comment: Problem must be elsewhere? This works: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnE4f/)

Comment: Are you sure you've included jQuery?

Comment: have a look here : http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/detect-screen-size-css-style/

Comment: Thank you. The issue was related the method that jquery was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your syntax, but you may want to check your browser has the most up-to-date version of your code!

Answer (score 0):

I tried many versions of what you have and it works for me so syntax is fine. Are you using a master page? If so, where is your script located, in master or the content page? I tried on a single page with no master using IE8.

To make sure your current JS code is loaded into the browser use Ctrl+F5 to do a total refresh, this should load any new JS files as well as CSS. If you are using IE then also hit F12 and try the developer tools to debug exactly where the error is happening. You should be able to dubug your script there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following just to test this and it worked just fine. Make sure you include jquery before you user $(document). Alternatively, try jQuery(document).ready() to see if that makes a difference. Some browsers don't recognize the $ alias for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(screen.width);
        if ((screen.width <= 1024)) {
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" type="text/css" />');
        }
    });
</script>
```